# WCF Data Services (OData) - Expand navigation properties using foreign key

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I am currently writing an OData service that is based on the WCF Dataservices Toolkit.

There are several objects that are exposed by the service an example of which is listed below.

```
public class Entitlement : IEntity
{
    #region Implementation of IEntity
    public string Id { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignProperty]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item : IEntity
{
    #region Implementation of IEntity
    public string Id { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public string ItemName { get; set; }  
}
```

Due to the data being retrieved from 2 separate data sources I only want to store the Id of the Item in the Entitlement object rather than the whole Item object.

This works for queries such as: Entitlement('1')/Item, the service understands that it needs to use the ItemId to perform the lookup.

However the problem occurs when I try and expand the Item using the below URL
   Entitlement('1')?$expand=Item

The Item always comes back as null, I understand that this is because I am not storing the Item on the entitlement object, but is there anyway that I can force OData to treat the expand statement the same way it treats the projection?

I have tried Entitlement('1')?$select=Item but this also comes back as null.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the objects referenced by a navigation property (collection), I think you need to use the $links syntax in the URI.

See [Section 3.2"Addressing Links Between Entities" in the OData Protocol URI Conventions doc](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#AddressingLinksBetweenEntries).

Comment: Hi @dthorpe the problem actually lies in the fact we are not using SQL and the entity framework. Because the data has to be resolved at runtime, we need to intercept the inbound request and manually get the extra data. Or we need to rewrite the expression tree and add the expand wrapper manually so that it will be picked up by our custom provider.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the $expand your module must have the virtual keyword on your linked property

```
public class Entitlement : IEntity
{
    #region Implementation of IEntity
    public string Id { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to use the oData query option  $expand

Entitlement('1')?$expand=Item

Comment: yes we went through the whole spec unfortunately were not using a relational provider that supported joining across collections/ tables. I have been meaning to post the workaround/fix that we used at the time.